# Zip files not getting created by System.IO.Compression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, system.io.compression

Can System.IO.Compression assembly create zip files of some specific files like .txt, .bak or it simply create zip file of directory? I am not being able to craete zip files of specific files but rather only the zip file of directory is getting created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [`ZipArchive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) object and then add individual files (including just one) by creating [`ZipArchiveEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry(v=vs.110).aspx) objects.

As a convenience, the [`ZipFileExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions(v=vs.110).aspx) class has an [`CreateEntryFromFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720(v=vs.110).aspx) method.